# Need help for AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, aws-lambda

I am working on one issue where I need Lambda to write the logs in S3 bucket but the tricky part here is, Lambda will read the logs and write in another s3 bucket which is in another AWS account. Can we achieve this?

I wrote some code but it isn't working.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import boto3
import os
import time

  BUCKET_NAME = '***'

  CSV_URL = f'***'

  def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = urlopen(CSV_URL)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_fileobj(response, BUCKET_NAME, time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    response.close()
```

Comment: So, are you basically asking how to allow the Lambda function to create an object in an Amazon S3 bucket that belongs to a different AWS Account?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking how to allow the Lambda function to create an object in an Amazon S3 bucket that belongs to a different AWS Account.

**Bucket Policy on target bucket**

The simplest method is to ask the owner of the target bucket (that is, somebody with Admin permissions in that other AWS Account) to add a **Bucket Policy** that permits `PutObject` access to the IAM Role being used by the AWS Lambda function. You will need to supply them with the ARN of the IAM Role being used by the Lambda function.

Also, make sure that the IAM Role has been given permission to write to the target bucket. Please note that two sets of permissions are required: The IAM Role needs to be allowed to write to the bucket in the other account, *AND* the bucket needs to permit access by the IAM Role. This double-set of permissions is required because access *both accounts* need to permit this access.

It is *possible* that you might need to grant some additional permissions, such as `PutObjectACL`.

**Assuming an IAM Role from the target account**

An alternative method (instead of using the Bucket Policy) is:

- Create an IAM Role in the target account and give it permission to access the bucket
- Grant trust permissions so that the IAM Role used by the Lambda function is allowed to 'Assume' the IAM Role in the target account
- Within the Lambda function, use the `AssumeRole()` API call to obtain credentials from the target account
- Use those credentials when connecting to S3, which will allow you to access the bucket in the other account

Frankly, creating the Bucket Policy is a lot easier.

Comment: Hi John, I will definitely work it out and looks like creating bucket policy is much easier and straight forward. One more point John, what if Lambda is in one of the custom VPC?

Comment: The 'location' of the Lambda function is irrelevant. What matters is the credentials _used_ by the Lambda function.